# get status of radio it active or clicked

Tags: android, layout, radio-button

i have two radio buttons in my program and im wondering how to get the status of the radio button if its click/active or not
rb_meter is one of the radio buttons
i tried using

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    if(rb_meter.isChecked()){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(DialogBox.this, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();   
    }else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(DialogBox.this, "not clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }

    }
```

and

```
    if(rb_meter.isEnabled()){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(DialogBox.this, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();   
    }else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(DialogBox.this, "not clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }

    }


if(rb_score.isSelected()){
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(DialogBox.this, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();   
}else{
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(DialogBox.this, "not clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

hope this works out for you :)

```
RadioButton radioButton=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(isChecked==true)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: is there a way to know if the radio button is active by clicking a button its like this i want o put a data in the textview but i need to check if the radio button of that text is clicked if it is clicked then i can add text on its edit text

Comment: Add this where you want to check it :) if(rb_meter.isChecked()){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }